# Unity list item not added

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

So basically I have 2 static lists I use as an object pool and 3 functions to interact with those lists. I've been storing the script attached to the gameObject because that what I want to do all the work on.

One to add the object to the list

```
public static void AddLightning(Lightning newLightning)
{
    lightningList.Add(newLightning);
}
```

One to remove the object from the active list, deactivate it and move it to the dead list

```
public static void RemoveLightning(Lightning oldLightning)
{
    lightningList.Remove(oldLightning);
    deadLightningList.Add(oldLightning);
    Debug.Log("Dead number in list: " + oldLightning.number);
    oldLightning.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //Debug.Log("adding dead Lightning" + deadLightningList.Count);
}
```

One To fetch a dead instance or make a new one if there are no dead ones left.

```
public static Lightning GetLightning()
{
    Lightning retLightning;
    //Debug.Log(deadLightningList.Count);
    if (deadLightningList.Count > 0)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Using dead Lighting");
        retLightning = deadLightningList[0];
        deadLightningList.RemoveAt(0);
        lightningList.Add(retLightning);
        return retLightning;
    }
    //Debug.Log("Adding New Lighting");
    GameObject newObject;
    newObject = Instantiate<GameObject>(lightningFab);
    retLightning = newObject.GetComponent<Lightning>();
    lightningList.Add(retLightning);
    retLightning.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    return retLightning;
}
```

This is the only code that requests a lightning instance

```
                float dmgMult = 1;
            float chainDamage = damage;

            Lightning lightning;
            lightning = GetLightning();
            lightning.SetTower(tower);
            lightning.SetNumber(lightningNum);
            lightningNum++;
            lightning.setTargets(chainList);

            foreach (mobBase mob in chainList)
            {
                chainDamage *= dmgMult;
                mob.DamageMob(chainDamage);
                //Debug.Log("Damage: " + chainDamage);
                dmgMult *= 0.8f;
            }
```

The lightning is set to kill itself after a fixed time and re-add itself to the dead list.

```
void OnEnable () {
    ProjectileBase.AddLightning(this); //Added to see if it would help, it doesnt
    lightningLine = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    timeKill = .2f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    setLine(targets);
    timeAlive += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timeAlive >= timeKill)
    {
        Debug.Log("Dead number Adding: " + number);
        ProjectileBase.RemoveLightning(this);
    }

}
```

The lightning properly deactivates itself when it's dead. But the list never seems to have more than one instance of the object inside it. I added the lightningNum to see if there was any pattern when it made a new one and it seems to be re-using the lightning at least once then forgetting about it all together.

ProjectileBase is where the static lists are held

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of things, the solution is a two-step process. First, have it so the your lightning isn't added to the pool during `OnEnable()`. When you create the Lightning, call an additional method, something like `Setup()`. The reason being, the Lightning will add itself to the pool **EVERY** time you re-activate it.

```
void Setup()
{
    ProjectileBase.AddLightning(this); //Added to see if it would help, it doesnt
    lightningLine = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    timeKill = .2f;
}
```

The second step is to actually re-activating your object when you remove it from your dead list.

```
public static Lightning GetLightning()
{
    Lightning retLightning;
    //Debug.Log(deadLightningList.Count);
    if (deadLightningList.Count > 0)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Using dead Lighting");
        retLightning = deadLightningList[0];
        deadLightningList.RemoveAt(0);
        lightningList.Add(retLightning);
        retLightning.gameObject.SetActive(true); // <-- Reactivate the object
        return retLightning;
    }
    //Debug.Log("Adding New Lighting");
    GameObject newObject;
    newObject = Instantiate<GameObject>(lightningFab);
    retLightning = newObject.GetComponent<Lightning>();
    lightningList.Add(retLightning);
    retLightning.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    return retLightning;
}
```

Alternatively, make sure you re-activating the lightning after you've gotten it. Either-or, but in the code you've supplied you haven't shown us re-activating it.

Now, although this wasn't asked by your question, have you considered a `Queue<Lightning>` collection, if you're simply taking the first, and adding it to the end of a list when finished with? It looks like every 0.2 seconds, you're deactivating the lightning and re-using an old one anyway. Two `List<Lightning>` collections may be adding more complexity than the problem warrants..?

Comment: That was the issue thank you very much. The adding it in the OnEnable was just there to help my try and troubleshoot it. Also does sound like a queue would work much simpler for this thanks again.